# convert some AS functions to php

Tags: php, actionscript

I converting a swf project to php, I'm not good with actionscript much so I need help to convert functions Hex.toArray, Hex.fromString, Base64.encodeByteArray in actionscript3 to php.

ActionScript

```
public function spawn(query_str:String, key:String, token:String = "") : String{
    var tmp1:* = key + "&" + token;
    var tmp2:* = Crypto.getHMAC("sha1");
    var tmp3:* = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(tmp1));
    var tmp4:* = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(query_str));
    var tmp5:* = tmp2.compute(tmp3, tmp4);
    return Base64.encodeByteArray(tmp5);
}
```

This is PHP function I converted, but results of two functions are different

```
function spawn($query_str, $key, $token = ''){
    $tmp1 = $key . "&" . $token;
    $tmp3 = pack("H*" , bin2hex($tmp1));
    $tmp4 = pack("H*" , bin2hex($query_str));
    $tmp5 = hash_hmac('sha1', $tmp4, $tmp3);
    return base64_encode($tmp5);
}
```

Comment: In hash_hmac you have put in arguments in reverse $tmp4 and then $tmp3. Is that expected?

Comment: Yes, because in AS is key, data. In php is data, key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex) in PHP, and [`pack("H*", ...)`](http://php.net/pack) in lieu of  [`hex2bin`](http://php.net/hex2bin). The primarily used base64 functions in PHP are [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode) and [`base64_decode`](http://php.net/base64_decode).

Arrays are seldomly used for data representation; binary data is generally kept in strings in PHP. But if really needed `$array = array_map("ord", str_split($string));` would do.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I edited my question, can you look at it?

Comment: I can only tell you that `pack("H*" , bin2hex($tmp1))` is pointless, as it first converts a string to hexnumbers, and the hexnumbers back to the string. And your variable names are impossible to follow.

Comment: Can you convert this line to php code for me? 

Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(str));